# What is the default value of Non-Nullable reference types in C# 8?

Tags: c#, non-nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

If I enable nullable reference types, what will be the value of the following string if I declare it like so?

```cs
string text;
```

Comment: That was also my question. If reference types are non-nullable why do they have `null` as their default values lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value will be `null`.

Bear in mind that the new system for nullable reference types will only *warn* you about problems, it will not give you an *error*, and that means that the code will still compile, with warnings.

If you declare this class:

```
public class Test
{ 
    private string text;
}
```

You'll get this warning for your class:

```
CS8618: Non-nullable field 'text' is uninitialized.
```

However, *the code still compiles*.

So to (again) answer your question, the default value for that field will be `null`.

**Note:** If you use that statement to declare a local variable, the answer is that it will not have a value, it will be considered definitely unassigned, and you're not allowed to read from that variable until you have code in place that makes it definitely assigned first.

---

As for warnings vs. errors, you can opt-in to get them as errors by fiddling with the project options and list the warnings you want to be treated as errors instead.