# Non-nullable default return null warning

Tags: c#, non-nullable

In C#8 we can now enable nullables, which means that reference types by default are considered not null by the compiler unless explicitly declared as nullable. Yet, it seems the compiler still throws a warning when trying to return a default generic with the `notnull` constraint. Consider the following example:

```
public TReturn TestMethod<TReturn>() where TReturn : notnull
{
    return default; // default is flagged with a compiler warning for possible null reference return
}
```

I thought maybe it would help if I also enforced that the return type must have an empty constructor, but it produces the same result:

```
public TReturn TestMethod<TReturn>() where TReturn : notnull, new()
{
    return default; // default is flagged with a compiler warning for possible null reference return
}
```

Why is the compiler flagging this line?

Comment: wait... `new()` does not mean "empty constructor"

Comment: `default` still means `null` for reference types.

Comment: I’m pretty certain `default` will always return `null` for classes. It won’t attempt to construct a new instance, even if there’s a default constructor.

Comment: @T.S.: Isn’t that exactly what the [`new()` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) suggests? “The new constraint specifies that a type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor.” Or am I missing a nuance between “parameterless” and “empty”?

Comment: @JeremyCaney "parameter-less" is not empty, no?... Yes

Comment: @HotN: With the `new()` constraint in place, you could instead call `return new TReturn()`.

Comment: @JeremyCaney "parameterless" means "has no parameters". "empty" means "has no body".  I suspect that OP meant the former.

Comment: @DStanley: Interesting, thank you! It seems I’ve been sloppy with my own nomenclature here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TReturn : notnull` means that `TReturn` must be a non-nullable type (which can be either a value type or a non-nullable reference type). Unfortunately, the [value of `default` for non-nullable reference types is still `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607785/what-is-the-default-value-of-non-nullable-reference-types-in-c-sharp-8), hence the compiler warning.

If you want the "default" for a non-nullable reference type to be whatever is created with a parameterless constructor, for example, you could do:

```
public TReturn TestMethod<TReturn>() where TReturn : notnull, new()
{
    return new TReturn(); 
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `return new TReturn()` with the ‘new()` constraint? That guarantees a parameterless constructor, and is simpler syntactically.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I had thought `new()` only worked for reference types - I was wrong...

Comment: Will this work if TReturn is a Guid? I'm worried that it won't be Guid.Empty.

Comment: This won't work if `TReturn` is `string` since it doesn't have a parameterless constructor.